# ios 6.1 annotation view like in standard map

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

much has been written about customizing the callout bubble for mkannotaionviews, but let me please ask for help on this one.

I want to mimic the default callout bubble from the 6.1 maps app, image + text rather than text only.

[A screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6fUc.png)

How would I do that? Can I somehow replace the view for the subtitle string?
The buttons left & right work, now I want the subtitle.

Thanks heaps,
El

Answer (score 0):

The Apple iOS sample code project "MapCallouts" may help.  Specifically, the MKAnnotation presented for "City" which is in the class `SFAnnotation`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I was thinking to generate a custom callout bubble that pops up when you hit the pin. In the apple example, one overrides the standard pin annotation. How can I generate a custom callout bubble but keep the pin?